# Forum with login/register

Tags: bbpress

I have worpdress with bbpress 2 plugin installed on domain in subdirectory "new". I added link to my private forum in menu. And now:
If I logged to admin panel, on site I can get to the forum, read topics, post messages etc. But when I logged out and click on link to forum I get error: "/new/forums/forum/qa/ not forund in this server".

Why when I logged in I can use the forum and when I logged out - wp is not find a forum?
I want the private forum - and register/login form for not logged in.